# Can I save username and password in a singleton in IOS Swift app?

Tags: ios, authentication, singleton, swift3, credentials

I am developing an IOS swift 3 app getting data from a restful web api. The first screen is the login screen. It asks for username and password. The app goes to the web api calling an authentication method ( anonymous accessible ) and return if the user is authenticated or not. The web api uses basic authentication.

In the ios app, I save the username and password in a singleton after successful log in. From then on, whenever I need to call the web api, I retrieve the username and password from the singleton and put them into my http header "Authorization" parameter. 
When the app closes, the singleton will go away. 
This seems to me is just like a desktop application which saves states. So why nobody is doing it? Everyone is doing either keychain, URLCredential etc.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save username and password in singleton. However, user will constantly required to enter username and password when the app is killed. Hence, keychain .
If your api supports Token after successfull login, you will want to save token as well

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My api does not support Token just yet. Maybe next round. I do use keychain too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Although it is not recommended since like neprocker says you will have to enter it again.

If your app uses tokens (like OAuth) for example, you should be saving ONLY the refresh token. Not the username or password, that's the idea of using tokens. The app shouldn't keep private information of the user.

Once the token expires, the app should request the user to enter username and password again to retrieve the token and save it again.